# In Python, is there a way to do a partial application with types?

Tags: python, python-typing

I'm trying to understand how to annotate a function that may be a method:

```py
from typing import Callable, Generic, Protocol, TypeVar, overload, Any

from typing_extensions import ParamSpec, Self, Concatenate

V_co = TypeVar("V_co", covariant=True)
U = TypeVar("U", contravariant=True)
P = ParamSpec("P")

class Wrapped(Protocol, Generic[P, V_co]):
    def __call__(self, /, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> V_co:
        ...

class MethodWrapped(Protocol, Generic[U, P, V_co]):
    def __call__(self, u: U, /, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> V_co:
        ...

    def __get__(self, instance: Any, owner: Any = None) -> Wrapped[P, V_co]:
        ...

@overload
def jit(f: Callable[Concatenate[U, P], V_co]) -> MethodWrapped[U, P, V_co]:  # type: ignore
    pass

@overload
def jit(f: Callable[P, V_co]) -> Wrapped[P, V_co]:  # pyright: ignore
    pass

def jit(f: Callable[..., Any]) -> Any:
    pass


class X:
    @jit
    def f(self, x: int) -> None:
        pass

@jit
def g(x: int, y: float) -> None:
    pass

x = X()
x.f(3)
x.f(x=3)
g(3, 4.2)
g(x=3, y=4.2)  # Fails!
reveal_type(x.f)
reveal_type(g.__call__)
```

Essentially, if `jit().__get__` is called with an instance, it should *partially apply* the function using that instance as the first argument.  Otherwise, it should return a callable with the same signature as the function.

(This is a question about annotations only.)